# Rails: undefined method `secrets'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I'm working on integrating the twilio-ruby gem into my application, however, I'm running into this error:

```
NoMethodError in NotificationsController#notify - undefined method `secrets' for #<Medy::Application:0x007f8dfcac1048>
```

Here is my notifications_controller.rb

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

class NotificationsController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def notify
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new Rails.application.secrets.twilio_account_sid, Rails.application.secrets.twilio_auth_token
    message = client.messages.create from: '+5555555555', to: '+5555555555', body: 'First ever MyMedy notifcation test.'
    render plain: message.status
  end

end
```

Here is my config/secrets.yml file - (I modified the secrets for this post):

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  twilio_account_sid: <%= ENV["AC5xxxxxxxxxxxxx"] %>
  twilio_auth_token: <%= ENV["ae6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"] %>

test:

production:
  secret_key_base: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  twilio_account_sid: <%= ENV["AC5xxxxxxxxxxxxx"] %>
  twilio_auth_token: <%= ENV["ae6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"] %>
```

I followed the Twilio tutorial [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/10/twilio-on-rails-part-2-rails-4-app-sending-sms-mms.html), however, I'm still getting the error.

Comment: What Rails version are you using? Secrets were introduced in 4.1

Comment: Rails 4.1.6 - I was using 4.0.6, but upgraded it after reading Secrets only worked in 4.1. However, it did not fix the error.

Comment: Did you also restart your Rails server after running the upgrade?

Comment: I didn't. But that seemed to work! Huge thanks. I'm running into a different error now. I will update above. If you want to add your response as an answer, I can select it as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was fixed by updating to Rails 4.1 then restarting the Rails server.